# $\textsf{Id}(P,1,\textsf{Type})\ \textit{true}$ and $P\ \textit{true}$

Tags: type-theory

I have a question about the following two judgments:

$$\textsf{Id}(P,1,\textsf{Type})\ \textit{true}\quad\quad\quad P\ \textit{true},$$

where $1$ is a unit type and $P$ is an arbitrary type. I know that they have different readings in type theory. My question is: do they both express the same meaning that $P$ is inhabited? Likewise, does $\textsf{Id}(P,0,\textsf{Type})\ \textit{true}$ express the same meaning as $\neg P\ \textit{true}$, that is, that $P$ is empty. Thanks!